# How to make sure OpenVPN stays connected?

Tags: openvpn, sysvinit

I followed some instructions from [here](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/24597/full-guide-set-up-pia-on-headless-ubuntu-with-transmission-and-port-forwarding-with-auto-reconnect) to connect to a VPN on startup, however, every few months something goes awry and I find myself *not* connected to the VPN.

How can I kill the internet if it can't connect to the VPN?

Comment: That seems a complicated way of getting a VPN running

Comment: @roaima Is there a simpler way to get PIA running on headless linux?

Comment: I've not used Private Internet Access myself, but I do have Debian-based Linux clients using OpenVPN to connect to remote networks. I imagine this is similar..? In these cases pretty much all I did was install the necessary connection.ovpn file to /etc/openvpn and redeclare it to `systemctl` (and before `systemd` came along I would edited `/etc/default/openvpn`)

Comment: @roaima Doesn't sound all that different then. I just had to download the .ovpn files from PIA, I used the systemctl/init.d script from that forum post but you can probably use any other one you find, maybe one is preinstalled. The only fancy bit is that PIA requires a password so you need to supply `--auth-user-pass`